# How to make test case for my queue code written in c?

Tags: c++, c, queue

how can I develop a test case(running all functions correct way in main)?

READ: because of the some reasons I cant post my code here giving me errors so I put image below and the code can be viewed from the following link.

[LINK IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTs8W.png) 
[LINK OF THE CODE](https://pastebin.com/JH5fKBpF)

I want to see the uses of `insert` and `remove` both removing and inserting and also test case for printing `underflow` and `overflow`. 
Examples; \

```
   insert("James") - inserts james \
   insert("Sarah") -> prints overflow \
   remove() - removes james \
   remove() - prints underflow \
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to get started with TDD in C++, or are you asking how you would structure a test case for your specific data structure?

Comment: I am looking to use the functions but I can't find a way to run them. Like how to insert and remove names and also get the `overflow` and `underflow` prints.

Comment: The code you linked doesn't actually call any of the functions you wrote your `printf()` calls in, so I'm not sure how you expect to get output. This question also shouldn't be tagged C++ if it's a C question, but I digress. 

If you want output from your functions, call them from `main()`.

Comment: I want help in writing `main()` function to call the functions and run them. Just want to see how to write `insert` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `insert`, you have:

```
if (q->rear = 5) {
```

This [unconditionally] *assigns* the value of `5` to `q->rear`

You want a *comparison*:

```
if (q->rear == 5) {
```

---

Note that `remove` is a standard function, so, when compiling, you get a conflict.

I've renamed `remove` to `dequeue` [and `insert` to `enqueue`].

Using loops can generate test code (e.g. you can enqueue and/or dequeue an *arbitrary* number times to generate edge cases).

Also, you do: `#define MAXQUEUE 6` but "hardwire" `5` everywhere. I'd replace that with (e.g.): `(MAXQUEUE - 1)`

Here's the corrected code with test cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXQUEUE        6
#define LASTQUEUE       (MAXQUEUE - 1)

struct queue {
    char items[MAXQUEUE];
    int front, rear;
};

struct queue q;

int
empty(struct queue *q)
{
    int temp;

#if 0
    temp = (q->front == q->rear) ? 1 : 0;
#else
    temp = (q->front == q->rear);
#endif

    return temp;
}

char
dequeue(struct queue *q)
{

    if (empty(q)) {
        printf("undeflow");
        exit(1);
    }

#if 0
    if (q->front == 5) {
        q->front = 0;
    }
    else {
        (q->front)++;
    }
#else
    if (q->front == LASTQUEUE) {
        q->front = 0;
    }
    else {
        (q->front)++;
    }
#endif

    return (q->items[q->front]);
}

int
enqueue(struct queue *q, char x)
{

// NOTE/BUG: "q->rear = 5" _assigns_ 5 to q->rear (need == instead)
#if 0
    if (q->rear = 5) {
        q->rear = 0;
    }
    else {
        (q->rear)++;
    }
#else
    if (q->rear == LASTQUEUE) {
        q->rear = 0;
    }
    else {
        (q->rear)++;
    }
#endif

    if (q->rear == q->front) {
        printf("overflow");
        (q->rear)--;
        if (q->rear == -1) {
#if 0
            q->rear = 5;
#else
            q->rear = LASTQUEUE;
#endif
        }
        return 0;
    }

    q->items[q->rear] = x;

    return 0;
}

int
main()
{
    q.front = q.rear = MAXQUEUE - 1;

    int lim = LASTQUEUE;

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < lim;  ++idx)
        enqueue(&q,idx);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < lim;  ++idx) {
        int val = dequeue(&q);
        printf("idx=%d val=%d\n",idx,val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but 1 problem. I want to enqueue str not int.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _want to enqueue str_. That's because `items` are individual `char`. So, at most, you could have _one_ "string". To have a list of _strings_ (e.g. `abc, def, hello, world, goodbye, galaxy`), a bit more code needs to be written. _If_ you could tolerate a fixed maximum for the string length(s), it is easy to change the `struct` and the functions. If you needed variable length strings, you'd have to do `strdup` and [later] `free` for the strings.